# Javascript - Cloned global variable getting overwritten

Tags: javascript

I have a set of charts on a webpage. I'd like to retain a copy of their data & DIV ID before modifying them so that I can reuse the static global copy at any time. ( This will be an array of original data of the charts). There also is a global changable copy of the same data called 'globalMasterList'.

Here is what I've tried so far. The problem I have is despite using "clone" method, to backup a static copy, there seems to some reference to the changable global copy. When I change the global changable copy, the static global copy also changes. I've spent a few days on this now but not able to figure out. I've  tried a few different things too without luck.

I'd appreciate any help to help me fix this please.

I have a set of charts on a webpage. I'd like to retain a copy of their data & DIV ID before modifying them so that I can reuse the static global copy at any time. ( This will be an array of original data of the charts). There also is a global changable copy of the same data called 'globalMasterList'.

Here is what I've tried so far. The problem I have is despite using "clone" method, to backup a static copy, there seems to some reference to the changable global copy. When I change the global changable copy, the static global copy also changes. I've spent a few days on this now but not able to figure out. I've  tried a few different things too without luck.

I'd appreciate any help to help me fix this please.

```
function modifyGroupingDefault() {
    var numDivs = 5;
    var divDrawId = 'div5';


    if (staticCopyoFGlobalCopy.length !== numDivs) {    
        staticCopyoFGlobalCopy.length = 0;  //  Clear the array just in case some junk elements have sneked in
        for (var x in masterList) { // Iterate through the charts on the web page
                var tempObj = {};   //  Temporary object
                tempObj.plotId = clone(globalMasterList[x].div.id); // Clone Div ID
                tempObj.divData = clone(globalMasterList[x].data);  // Clone the dataset
                staticCopyoFGlobalCopy.push(tempObj);   //  Push the cloned object into array
        }
    }

    for (var x in globalMasterList) {
        if (globalMasterList[x].div.id === divDrawId) { // Check if the current Div ID in the iteration loop is the Div ID of the chart whose groupingbutton is clicked
            delete globalMasterList[x].dataset; //  Remove the chart's data provider
            for (y in staticCopyoFGlobalCopy) { //  Iterate through the static/non-changable global copy
                if (staticCopyoFGlobalCopy[y].plotId === divDrawId) {   
                    globalMasterList[x].data = staticCopyoFGlobalCopy[y].divData;   // Set the current chart's data to the dataset from the immutable chart array
                    // Some operation on globalMasterList
                    //Some operation onglobalMasterList
                    // Some operation onglobalMasterList
break;  // Goal achieved. break out
                }
            }
            break;  // Goal achieved. Break out
        }
    }
}

/*
    *
    *   Clone function
    *
*/

function clone(obj) {
    var copy;
    // Handle the 3 simple types, and null or undefined
    if (null === obj || "object" !== typeof obj)
        return obj;
    // Handle Date
    if (obj instanceof Date) {
        copy = new Date();
        copy.setTime(obj.getTime());
        return copy;
    }

    // Handle Array
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        copy = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; ++i) {
            copy[i] = clone(obj[i]);
        }
        return copy;
    }

    // Handle Object
    if (obj instanceof Object) {
        copy = {};
        for (var attr in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr))
                copy[attr] = clone(obj[attr]);
        }
        return copy;
    }
    throw new Error("Unable to copy obj! Its type isn't supported.");
}
```

Comment: `localCopyofMasterList` is not actually a copy, it's the same list.

Comment: Perhaps you should start by cloning.. `var localCopyOfMasterList = clone(globalMasterList);`

Comment: Hello Barmar - Thank you. Yes you are right. It's a stray entry there from a lot fiddling I've been doing.Any thoughts on the cloning part please? I've just updated the code in the question

Comment: Hello Travis - Many thanks for jumping in. I prefer to clone only a part of it as the full array has a lot of cyclic references. It;s a massive one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved long ago. Closing for formalities.